# Minification error using .net mvc BundleConfig for Angular 1.3.9 only ngAnimate

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, minify, bundling-and-minification

We are developing a large ASP.net MVC 4 + Angular application. Some time in the last months the minification/bundling seems to have broken.

This is the error we are recieving:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
    (27211,145-152): run-time error JS1019: Can't have 'break' outside of loop: break a
*/
```

I have tracked down the error to ngAnimate and we are using the minified version from https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular-animate.min.js

And this is what our BundleScripts method in BundleConfig.cs looks like:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app.js").Include(
            "~/Content/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3/modernizr.js",
            "~/Content/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.1/jquery.min.js",
            "~/Content/js/vendor/angular-1.3.9/angular.min.js",
            "~/Content/js/vendor/angular-1.3.9/i18n/angular-locale_sv-se.js",
            "~/Content/js/vendor/angular-1.3.9/angular-animate.min.js",
            "~/Content/js/vendor/angular-1.3.9/angular-touch.min.js",
            "~/Content/js/vendor/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js",
            "~/Content/js/vendor/ui-bootstrap-2.4.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/vendor/clipboardjs-1.6.1/clipboard.min.js")
            .Include("~/Content/js/vendor/ngclipboard-1.1.1/ngclipboard.min.js")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/Content/js/vendor/ui-bootstrap-2.4.0-sb", "*.js", true)
            .Include("~/Content/js/runfirst.js")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/Content/js/app", "*.js", true)
            .Include(ClientJsConfig.BundlePath));
```

Things I've tried:

- Commenting out every item to see which file is causing the problem
- Changing the order of the files
- Used the unminified version to let Visual Studio minify it on it's own

Things I would like to avoid:

- Updating Angular, as that would require the whole site to be tested and we are close to a release

Could this be a bug in this version of the framework?
What solution would you recommend to fix this error?

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Can you show how you have injected ng-animate in your module?

Comment: in app.js

`angular.module('ewae',
 [
  'ngAnimate', ..., ...]`